# Is there an specific order to install the following packages?

Tags: numpy, opencv, matplotlib, scipy, installation

I want to install numpy, scipy, matplotlib, and opencv

I do not want to mess it up. Not sure if there is a specific order I should install them or if I can do any.

I know opencv should be the last because requires numpy. 
What about the others?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you try `Anaconda` distribution? It makes lot of things simple

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you explain me why anaconda would be easier? are all these packages already in anaconda? many thanks

Comment: Your questions lacks a bit of specificity. While as a first solution Anaconda is fine, depening on your platform and needs other solutions exist. So, what is your platform? Do you need a specific version of Python? Will you need to compile C/Fortran extension modules, etc?

Comment: Sorry Pierre. I am using Ubuntu 16.10. I am using python for scientific software. Not sure about the last question. From other answers I guess I should use Anaconda and then Opencv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per OP's interest, I would like to suggest the installation of [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It includes the packages `NumPy`, `SciPy`, `Scikit Image`, `Matplotlib`, `Jupyter` and over 100 libraries as *pre-built* packages as [documented here.](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) (choose specific python version as you like)

Once anaconda installation is finished, you can easily install `opencv` from the command prompt like:

```
# install opencv
$ conda install opencv
```

It's very easy to search for a package and install it using the `conda` package manager.

Comment: I would put my bet on this!

Comment: That sounds perfect for what I am looking. I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First I suggest always to use a virtualenv for all projects (see here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Think of it as a type of insurance that enables you to roll back or re-do things in case you mess things up.

Second, when you usually install a python package python checks for dependencies and install them (at least with pip install). However, it does not hurt to do things in the right order- you can find those dependencies on the python documentation of these specific packages. For example, opencv requires numpy as a dependency (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python).

Order:
1) numpy
2) scipy
3) matplotlib and opencv